# Beggining in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, beginner

I just want to know which books, courses,videos, links,etc do you recommend me to start in machine learning, neural networks, languajes most commonly used. I want to start from zero, just in the begging of all beacuse I have not experience in this kind of algorithms but it's something that call my attention. Thank you!

Comment: I have voted to close the question as opinion-based (because what is good for one person is not good for another, it depends what you already know and how you learn), but you could try Coursera course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning - there is a new group session starting in 2 weeks. I have done that course and enjoyed it.

Comment: What if the OP added the reference request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coursera is currently offering a course on Machine learning with collaboration from MIT. Many says its strongly recommended.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

But I found the below course from Edx more interesting.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

It also provides hands on the Microsofts New exclusive Machine learning platform On Azure.

Comment: can you provide me the Edx course link? you duplicated the coursera link.thanks

Comment: https://www.edx.org/course/data-science-machine-learning-essentials-microsoft-dat203x